# Can I select every row and limit the ones with a diferent value?

Tags: mysql

Let's say I have a table with columns like this: `'text'`, `'id'` and I want so select all columns that have the id 1 and I want to limit all the columns that have an id of null.

`SELECT text, id FROM table_name WHERE id = 1 ..LIMIT 2 WHERE id = null ? ..`

I think I have to somehow use a second query, but I don't know really know how ?

```
SELECT text, id FROM table_name
INNER JOIN (SELECT text, id WHERE id = NULL LIMIT 2) as second ON .. on what  
should I join them ? .. WHERE id = 1
```

How can I select all the columns with the id of one and limit the ones that have an id of null ?

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/82c211)

I want to select all rows that have the id of 1 and select only 2 rows where the id is null.

Comment: Can you add some sample data and expected results please?

Comment: Your question is somewhat unclear - it seems that the requirements `id = 1` and `id IS NULL` are contradictory. Could you please add sample data and expected output, as already requested by @RyanWilson ?

Answer (score 0):

If you use a CTE, then you should be able to limit the results coming back within that CTE(common table expression)

```
WITH limit AS 
(
  SELECT id, text FROM table_name WHERE id IS NULL
  LIMIT 2
)
SELECT id, text FROM table_name WHERE is = 1
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM limit;
```

Comment: `with` requires mysql 8 or mariadb 10.2.1.  but there's no need for it for this problem?

Comment: Sure, it was just tagged MySQL though, so I assume latest version. But you’re right that you can just use a union with a sub-query. My personal habit is to use CTE’s though. I think they make the sql easier to read

Answer (score 0):

You want a union.

```
SELECT text, id FROM table_name WHERE id = 1
UNION ALL
(SELECT text, id FROM table_name WHERE id is null LIMIT 2)
```

The parentheses are needed to keep the limit from applying to the entire union, not just the second select.

Comment: `WHERE id = null` will not return anything. It should be `WHERE id IS null`